# Unstretchable Splash Screen

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, splash-screen

I'm trying to make a splash screen that can't be stretched. Using a 9 patch image doesn't really since there's no region that can be stretched. However, area around the centered logo can be cut off. Is there any way to achieve this effect with Cordova?

I'm only interested in compiling it into an Android app.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the cordova-splash npm module. You can install it on a system that has Node.js installed with the following command `npm install cordova-splash -g` this then allows you to take one image and generate all the splash screen images for all the necessary resolutions. Works great for me.